# I can't apply glide with firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I can get link with this, i tested with realtime database on firebase but i'cant use link as a String.but when i write like  Glide.with(this).load("link").into(imageView);

```java
public void run() {
    imgRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            imgUrl = uri.toString();
            myImg.setValue(imgUrl);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("foto linki yollanamadı.");
        }
    });
}

thread.start();
Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
```

I tried lots of things. How can I solve this. I want to use as a string like that:

```java
Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
```

Comment: getDownloadUrl is asynchronous and returns immediately before the URL is available.  You can't use `imageUrl` until after the callback is invoked.  It looks like you're trying to use it before the URL is actually loaded. You should add some logging to see how it's actually working.

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you understand Kotlin, then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
    Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
```

Is being called outside the thread where you are initializing **imgUrl** at which point the **getDownloadUrl()** task is not done.

You need to call it after the task is done and from the main thread.
Your run block should therefore look like below

```
    imgRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            imgUrl = uri.toString();
            myImg.setValue(imgUrl);
//Change start
runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);                
    }
});
//Change end

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("foto linki yollanamadı.");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the download URL of a file from the Firebase Storage, you actually perform an asynchronous operation. What you need to understand is that such an operation takes time. How much time it will take? We don't know, as it depends on too many factors. So when you attach a listener to such an operation, the `onSuccess()` method will fire when the operation for getting the download URL is successful. This means that by the time you're using:

```
Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
```

The operation for getting the download URL isn't complete, that's why the `imgUrl` is null. The solution is always the same. Any code that needs data from an asynchronous operation, needs to be inside the `onSuccess()` method or be called from there. So in your case that would be:

```
public void run() {
    imgRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            imgUrl = uri.toString();
            myImg.setValue(imgUrl);
            Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageView); //
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("foto linki yollanamadı.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Kenan. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?